# viewForFooterInSection did finish loading

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, view, footer

I am trying to change the elements on my section footer directly as it finish loading

But when i try following way

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView* footerView = [self.tableView footerViewForSection:0];
}
```

footerView returns nil

The only solution that works for me is `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`

Shouldn't there exist a delegate method like the one mentioned above but with `didDisplayFooterView` instead?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you use the `view` parameter passed in this method?

Comment: `willDisplayFooterView` as in "it will be displayed in the future". Of course you can't get it from the tableView, because it hasn't been displayed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your footer view is passed in as a the parameter `view`. Just check that the section is the one you want:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:   (NSInteger)section {

  if(section == 0) {
    //view is your footer view
  }
}
```